# "null_value" not permitted for "text" field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to define a "null_value" for a "text" field (ver. 5.1.1). Like so:

```
PUT students
{
  "mappings": {
    "student": {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "null_value": "No First Name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This results in an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Mapping definition for [first_name] has unsupported parameters:  [null_value : No First Name]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [student]: Mapping definition for [first_name] has unsupported parameters:  [null_value : No First Name]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Mapping definition for [first_name] has unsupported parameters:  [null_value : No First Name]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

But if "first_name" is marked as `"type": "keyword"`, it succeeds. Looking at the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html), it doesn't state that "null_value" applies only to "keyword" typed fields. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `null_value` is not allowed in `text` datatype. Take a look at table for allowed parameters for `text` datatype. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/text.html#text-params

Comment: Thanks @Sandyandi N. dela Cruz. I guess it doesn't make sense to analyze what would be a null value moniker. If you post this as an answer, I am happy to accept it.

Comment: You're welcome @Ram. Posted as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null_value` is not allowed in `text` datatype. Take a look at table for allowed parameters for `text` datatype. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/text.html#text-params